# How to use AVQueuePlayer nad AVPlayerItem

Tags: objective-c, audio, foundation, avplayeritem

Im trying to use AVQueuePlayer class to play some AVPlayerItems and have problems with it.

I have class with property

```
    @property AVPlayerItem *palnik;
```

In init of this class i have:

```
    NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"palnik" withExtension:@"wav"];
    self.palnik = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:audioFileLocationURL];
```

And later one functions have sth like this

```
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.palnik, nil];
    AVQueuePlayer *playQueue = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:array];
    [playQueue play];
```

And I dont hear anything. The path is 100% correct. I've tested it with AVAudioPlayer but I need to play more than one file one after another thats why I would like to use AVQueuePlayer

Answer (score 0):

I found how to fix it but I have no idea what was the problem...

I just put

```
 AVQueuePlayer *playQueue
```

as a @property and now playing it with

```
 [self.playQueue play]
```

it started to work... Can anyone explain me why?